# Commutator evaluation within sympy.physics.secondquant

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to symbolically compute commutators of creation and annihilation operators from the [sympy.physics.secondquant](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/secondquant.html) package. My particular problem is that I can't get the same outputs from Commutator and from computation by hand and I can't get sympy to simplify the expressions. I work on python `3.7.1` and sympy `1.3`.

The [Commutator](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/physics/secondquant.html#Commutator) returns the expression unevaluated if there are more than two Creation/Annihilation operators provided. In that case, we need to evaluate such a thing with the `.doit()` function. However I can't seem to get the `.doit()` to work properly.

For example:

```
from sympy.physics.secondquant import Commutator, B, Bd
Commutator(B(0), Bd(0))
>>> 1
```

but this should be the same as:

```
(B(0) * Bd(0) - Bd(0) * B(0)).doit()
>>> AnnihilateBoson(0)*CreateBoson(0) - CreateBoson(0)*AnnihilateBoson(0)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get sympy to simplify this expression to 1. (I have tried using simplify, it didn't work).

In my use-case I wanted to compute

```
Commutator(B(0), Bd(0) ** 2)
>>>Commutator(b(0),CreateBoson(0)**2)
```

where B(0) becomes b(0) in the output for some reason!

Applying `.doit()` results in `>>>AnnihilateBoson(0)*CreateBoson(0)**2 - CreateBoson(0)**2*AnnihilateBoson(0)` instead of simplifying to `2*AnnihilateBoson(0)`.